# Getting info of live http request in application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Is there any way in JavaScript to fetch info about all http request which are in progress state now.

Answer (score 0):

> With jQuery you can use the **Ajax events API**

**.ajaxSend()** http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/

**.ajaxComplete()** http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

**Complete list of jQuery Ajax events:** https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

> Example:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(){
    alert('Sending an Ajax request.');
})
```